# Extract delimited word from a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Using Excel 2010, I have 4 cells with the data below:

c:/Tree/**Fuit**/Apple

c:/Tree/**Fuit**/Pear

c:/Tree/**Trunk**/Upper

c:/Tree/Leaf/**Small**/Needle

I cannot figure out the formula to extract the words highlighted as bald.
Basically I need the word delimited by the last 2 slash characters.

Comment: Use `find` or `replace` to get the second and third `/` then `mid`.

Comment: @findwindow I added more sample. The preceding words may vary in number.

Comment: If you have got Excel 2013 and onwards you could also use: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should work for you:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*2),LEN(A1)))
```

Simplified, but make sure the number used is *always* going to be longer than the number of characters in the cell (I'm just guessing that 999 will be sufficient):

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),999*2),999))
```

And throwing this in just in case you prefer to use a single `MID` function instead of a `LEFT(RIGHT(..))` pair:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),999*(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1),999))
```

Comment: that did it, thank you! need to examine in its details to learn something at least ...